# List.split output trouble

Tags: python

I was practicing some coding and I decided to make a parrot translator. The basic point of this game is, that after every word in a sentence, you should put the syllable "pa". I had written the code for that:

```
    print("This is the PARROT Translator!")
    original = input("Please enter a sentence you want to translate: ")

    words = list(original.split())

    for words in words:
         print(words + "pa")
```

but the problem I have and I dont know how to fix is, when I split the sentence, the output wont be in the same line, but every word will be at it's own.

Comment: Notice that you should write `for word in words:` not `for words in words:`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print without newline or space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-newline-or-space)

Answer (score 3):

You should use `end=""` at the end of your print:

```
print(words + "pa", end="")
```

EDIT:

For explanation you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-newline-or-space)

Answer (score 0):

I am not very good in python, so possibly you will have some issues with version support, but this should work in most cases

```
import sys

print("This is the PARROT Translator!")
original = input("Please enter a sentence you want to translate: ")

words = list(original.split())

for word in words:
  sys.stdout.write(word + "pa")
```